# Save and use function action in other class and change it

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, delegates

I have `WinForms` application. It have `Form` and my self control (Panel with other `TextBoxes` and other controls) on it. Near it control I have a button. Button have `onClick` event

```
A(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Method **A** change my control to next control (Also panel with controls).
But I want to do check data in my control when I press button.
**Not all** controls needs to check data in it.

Can I save address of **A** to variable and send to Control? In control I want to change button Event to **B(object sender, EventArgs e)** and if B successfull change **B** to **A** again. And call

```
Button.PerformClick()
```

My problem: I dont know how save metod `A(object sender, EventArgs e)` to variable for send it in control.

Is it possible?

Comment: "Method A change my control to next control" Does this mean you want to loop through your tabs containing the panels? I´m not sure I understand what you´re trying to do. Furthermore your question is quite unclear without any code shown.

Comment: Yes, I have List of panels and change it by button. For example testing or Installer app. Every control doing unique work.

Comment: Code is very large to show.

Comment: I have a lot of panels with unique tasks. Global general handler must to know about all tasks and check it? Its class will be grow up and more more more. I already have more then 20 unique tasks, and I will add new, because app have a lot of logic branches and launch modes. Thats why I deside that only control know what and how he do its work.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you really are trying to do but...I think what you want is using a interface to have a handler method common to all your user controls and just call it on button click...

Comment: Ok, I think I can create CustomUserControl class and put in it virtual method **Validate()**, and all my panels just change parent to it CustomUserControl class. And in button event call panel.Validate()